# Sending data from server to all the client using spring websocket java

Tags: java, spring, spring-websocket

I have create a thread in spring application which is called at the start of the spring boot application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        Thread th = new Thread(new Countdown());
        th.start();

    }
}
```

Inside that I have created a variable which decreases by 1 every second.

```
public class Countdown implements Runnable{
    private static volatile int count=0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.runTimer();

    }

    public void runTimer(){
        count=60;
        while(count>0){
            System.out.println("Countdown : "+count+" "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
            try{
                count--;
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I wanted to achieve is that after count-- operation I should be able to send the count value to all the clients connected to the server. The count value should be send without any request from the client.

Here is the WebSocket configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

I tried using SimpMessageTemplate object to send the count. But it is only working when the client sends a request. I tried to use the SimpMessageTemplate object in Countdown class after count-- operation but its giving me null exception.

```
@Controller
public class CountdownWSController {

    private Countdown countdown;
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;


    public CountdownWSController(Countdown cnt, SimpMessagingTemplate template){
        this.template = template;
        countdown = cnt;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/client")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public void countDownService(int count) throws Exception{
            this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", new CountdownModel(count));

    }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's only working when client send request cause you have used  @MessageMapping("/client"). It means that counDonwService is mapped with "/client" websocket endpoint. I don't know if you are interresting by schedule the call of countDownService, so take a look of @Scheduled (https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

Comment: Hi @Farfetch'd thanks a lot. Its working completely fine. Is there any way if I can do this without multithreading.

Comment: Hi @DKB I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve. You are trying to send the count to all client when value equals to 0 ?

Comment: Hi @Farfetch'd I just want to create a server which will share live countdown to the all the connected clients like 60 59 58 57.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to do that without using multi threading

```
@Controller
public class CountdownWSController {

    private int countdown;
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;


    public CountdownWSController(Countdown cnt, SimpMessagingTemplate template){
        this.template = template;
        countdown = 60; /* Choose the starting value */
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void countDownService() {
            this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", this.count);
            this.count=this.count-1;

    }

}
```

However, with this way if there are two clients the timer will be the same even if they join the communication at different time